# Wrong certificate used when using the Windows L2TP VPN client

Tags: windows, vpn, certificate, l2tp

I have my VPN security gateway configured to only allow clients having a VPN computer certificate issued by a specific CA.
Such a certificate is correctly installed on the client side.
In addition to that, another machine certificate is installed on the same client and needed for other purposes.

Now, when the Windows L2TP client tries to establish a connection, it presents the *other* certificate to the Security Gateway. It does not use the certificate the Security gateway is looking for, which results in the VPN connection being rejected by the Security Gateway.

How can I force the L2TP client to use my VPN certificate issued from the correct CA and recognized by the Security Gateway instead of using certificates intended for other purposes?

Best regards,
Tom

Comment: Any news on that? Same problem to me!

Comment: I changed our VPN setup so that we don't need this certificate in the Windows cert store anymore. I guess that scenario is not possible in Windows, but I still don't know for sure.

Comment: So that means, that you changed from Certificate to Passphrase?